# Facebook access token missing expiry property (after offline_access deprecations)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I have a FB app that used to ask for offline_access permission. At some point I changed that and to use the 60 days valid access_tokens.

Now, I am storing in db the access token and the expiration time (that comes as an integer in ms along with it). Every time when a user is using the app and he still have a valid token (I check the expiry time) I try to extend that token (no more than once per day).

My problem is that I start getting new tokens without an expiry field. When I check some of those with the debugger it says that never expires.

How is that possible? 
Wasn't offline_access removed on 5th of December?
How can I be sure that every time when I request an access token I get one with an expiry time?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook still issues tokens that never expire if page access tokens are requested for the user as well.

The flow goes something like this (facebook responses in *italics*) :

- Request initial user token

  - *oauth token granted with expire time of 60 days from now*
- Request page tokens for pages the user is an adminitrator on

  - *oauth tokens granted for all pages and user token is extended to never expire (unless revoked).*

There isn't a lot of documentation on this on any of facebook's pages but I have tested this pretty extensively and it happens every time.